# SWI-PROLOG How to use library(clpqr) solver predicates

Tags: prolog, clpr

I am failing with using the predicates from the library CLPQR in SWI-Prolog. The library itself works. Expressions like "clpq: {X = 5^2}" are solved correctly. But I can't figure out how to use "minimize", "maximize", "inf", "sup", etc. 
Link to the Prolog Manual http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpqr. I'd really appreciate if anybody can give some Code Examples!!

Comment: "clpq: minimize(Y^2)."   returns   "{Y^2=_2312, minimize_lin(_2312)}." But what I would expect is something like "Y=0"